# How to split digit which is in combination with a character from string array? (eg.c1)

Tags: java, sql, arrays, string, auto-increment

I have a table:'Categories' which has two fields:Category_ID and Category. Data in Category_ID field are like 'c1','c2'. If There are 10 rows then from c1 to c10. When I insert new record in this table,how can I set the Category_ID like c11 or c12? If none of the record is deleted then its easy to set it according to number of rows.But User can delete the records. I have tried to retrieve Category_ID from the table, stored it in vector, then set one string variable which stores all category_ids separated by ';' I thought to separate c and related digit from Category_ID so that can use the next digit in insert query.

```
   Statement st;
   ResultSet rsCatID;

   String query="";
   String querySelect="";//used to get last category_id number,so that next value will be applied in insert query.
   Vector vCatID=new Vector();
   String strCatID="";
   String[] arrCatID;
```

Then in try catch block-lines after connection,

```
       querySelect="select Category_ID from Categories";
       rsCatID=st.executeQuery(querySelect);
       while(rsCatID.next()){
            vCatID.add(rsCatID.getString("Category_ID").toString());
       }
       for(int i=0;i<vCatID.size();i++){
           strCatID+=vCatID.get(i).toString()+";";
       }

       System.out.println("strcatidcount=="+strCatID);

       arrCatID=strCatID.split(";");
       for(int i=0;i<arrCatID.length;i++){
            System.out.println("arrCatID=="+arrCatID[i]);
       }
```

Now want to split digit from array and want to insert next value and attached it with the character 'c' and insert the whole new record. How can I split it? eg. if category_id is c3 then 3 must be stored in another array and for new record 4 ,(c4) will be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX((CAST(REPLACE(Category_ID,'C','') AS INT))) from Categories
```

ALTERNATIVELY:

```
SELECT MAX(cint(MID(Category_ID,2))) FROM Categories;
```

This will bring the highest intnum back

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am using Microsfot Access so Cast function doesnt work. I have used CINT funtion, and now its working.

Comment: Its working in MS Access' sql view. But giving me an error while compling my java file.                                    [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'REPLACE' in expression

Comment: It's very very weird but you can use the following function if you know that the first character will always be the one you will remove: SELECT MAX(cint(MID(Category_ID,2)))
FROM Categories;

Comment: I have even tried to create a new query in ms access and pasted  query with replace function and in java file, I used 'select * from query1' But still its giving the same error. Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Have you tried the alternative method I've supplied, it seems the jet engine does not support the replace function even though access does?

Comment: Yes I am trying but its giving me Invalid Descriptor Index error. There is only one column so used rsCatId.getString(0) Then why its giving this error.This query also works fine in ms access.

Comment: I have got no idea what that error is, it looks like something native to java, access sucks :-)

Comment: cool man, sorry could't help anymore, let me know if you get a fix

Comment: Yeah sure.Lets see it will waste how many of my minutes or hours. Trying really hard for it..

Comment: Finally..:-) rsCatId.first(); cnt=Integer.valueOf(rsCatID.getString(1));  //stored that max value in integer variable.

Comment: And used that alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

This is way too complicated! Just use an autoincrement field. Why does the category field have to start with the letter c anyway? Why can't it just be an integer? If you need it to display starting with a 'c' in your application, you can just modify the values whenever you read them from the database, but keep them as integers in the database. That will be more efficient and allow you to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the first choice is always to use autoincrement field.But due to certain requirements,I cant use it.